# How to shift cells down automatically when insert and then hit Enter on Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On my personal accounting sheet, I'd like to see my newest information at the top, ever. Then, I'd like to use row 16 to input the values, then when I hit Enter it shifts down the cells automatically so that the newest information is ever on the top (row 17).

I can do it by inserting a new row manually, but I want to automatize that.

The data contains 4 values: Description, Type, Value, and Date. (the screen-shot is Portuguese)

If this is not possible, I'd like to know further alternatives as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can trigger a script from pressing 'enter' but I may be wrong. If that gets found then this would be a great starting point that would be easy to modify.

This script will check that cell `B16` has a value and run upon editing range `E16` (pressing enter key or simply clicking out of).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E16'); //<<< Change Your Range/Named Ranged Here
  var adjacentCell = myRange.offset(0,-3); //<<< Checks Cell B16 For A Value Before Aadding New Row

  //Let's get the row & column indexes of the active cell
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  //Check that your active cell is within your named range
  if (col >= myRange.getColumn() && col <= myRange.getLastColumn() && row >= myRange.getRow() && row <= myRange.getLastRow() && adjacentCell.getValue() != '') {
    autoNewRow(e);
  }
}


function autoNewRow(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRows(16,1);
};
```

It simply adds a new row below row 16.